# GitPython: error: Module "git" does not explicitly export attribute "Repo" [attr-defined]

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, gitpython

I am using Python 3.10.4, [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) version 3.1.31, [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) version 1.4.1:

```
$ pip show GitPython
Name: GitPython
Version: 3.1.31
Location: /home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: gitdb

$ python --version
Python 3.10.4

$ mypy --version
mypy 1.4.1 (compiled: yes)
```

If run `mypy` on this minimal example (`git-python-types.py`) :

```
import git
repo = git.Repo('some_dir')
```

I get the following error:

```
$ mypy --strict git-python-types.py 
git-python-types.py:3: error: Module "git" does not explicitly export attribute "Repo"  [attr-defined]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Any ideas on why this error occurs and how to fix it?

### Some clues

I can see the following line in the GitPython [source code](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/c09a71e2caefd5c25195b0b2decc8177d658216a/git/__init__.py#L49) :

```
from git.repo import Repo  # @NoMove @IgnorePep8
```

but I am not sure if `mypy` is reading this line or not.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't get an attribute error if you run the code?

Comment: Yes the code runs without errors (using this command line: `python git-python-types.py`)

Comment: The tools are not omniscient.  Especially when using `--strict`, false positives do occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documentation suggests this is proper usage

https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#meet-the-repo-type

```py
from git import Repo
...
```

then I would consider this a minor bug that should be fixed in GitPython.

You can work around this bug by importing it from the submodule

```py
git.repo.Repo('some_dir')
```

or don't use strict. The check it adds here is `--no-implicit-reexport`, which GitPython currently breaks.

Comment: Thanks! Yes running mypy like this works also: `mypy --strict --implicit-reexport git-python-types.py`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to import it like the following example.

```
from git.repo import Repo
```

This is working in  Neovim using pyright as LSP.

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: But surely this is not the intended way to import `Repo`.